# How to use <%= item %> in Jquery in EJS?

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, ejs

How to use `<%= item %>` in jquery in EJS?

I can use it like this in `<html>` tags but I wonder if I can use it in `<script>` tags.

```
<strong> <%= userx.email %></strong>
```

What I want is :

```
var email =  userx.email;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var email = "";
   email = "<%=userx.email%>";
</script>
```

That's it.

Comment: It's not printing anything when I debug.

Comment: The syntax is right. Please make sure your attribute userx.email is returning a value or not.

Comment: It's returning and I can see it in HTML tags. The problem is `<script type="text/javascript">` is not working in EJS, I guess. Because I can't even log anything in it.